# Share parent folder properties with child files e.g. word, excel

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, search-results, folder, metadata

I'm currently looking to set up a sharepoint library which is to store the multiple files for separate customers.

The biggest issue i'm facing is to integrate it fully with the search functionality of the site.

I've managed to set them into a folder which you select the values for e.g. customer name, prn, model number. However how do i get it so it automatically shares these with the items saved into this folder?

Comment: You don't mention the term DocumentSet; I do hope you are using those (available since SharePoint 2010) They are meant to order documents in special type folders (DocumentSets) which *can* inherent metadata from the 'parent' 'folder/docset'

Comment: @DannyEngelman Yeah i've done that but they're still not inheriting the parent metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, here's how to do it:

> I understand that you want the documents inside a document set all inherit the same metadata column from document set. You will need to set the metadata column as Shared Columns for the document set content type.
>
> 1. Click Library Settings.
> 2. Click on Document Set content type to edit it(If all the content types are not shown, you can check ‘Allow Management of content types in Advanced Settings’).
> 3. Click Document Set settings. Add the metadata columns as Shared Columns. In this way, when you upload or create a new document in the document set, it will have the same metadata as the document set.

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fc4f6429-0a2c-404b-9b7b-8ecad7646b32/documents-in-a-document-set-are-not-inheriting-metadata?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: When copy pasting answers you use make it very clear that you have copied it, and from where!

Comment: What is Shared column, I don't see it in Online. What feature makes column sharing, "Metadata"?..

Answer (score 2):

You would want to go into the document library settings and look at the Column Default values link. In here you can set the default column values for files placed into the folders. They will automatically pick up the values specified on the folder.

Comment: can we do it for library w/o document set?